# Using Rollup for a React Component Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundling-and-minification, rollup, tree-shaking

I am beginning to learn a bit about bundling as I am working on updating a small, internal React component library which uses Rollup.

**Current State**

Right now, all of the components are being bundled down into one `index.js` files. And whenever I import one or multiple...

```
import { Button, Input } from 'my-library';
```

...the entire library is being imported. I would like to fix that.

At this point, I have updated Rollup to create named component files so I can do imports like this:

```
import Button from 'my-library/Button';
```

That is fine when I am using just one component but whenever I need more than one, it feels redundant to have to have, for example, five lines of imports from the same library. But whenever I again try to destructure them, the entire library is imported.

**The Goal**

I would like to have the ability to run that same destructured import statement from above but **only** import those two components.

**rollup.config**

```
export default {
  experimentalCodeSplitting: true,
  input: [
    'src/index.js',
    'src/components/Button/Button.js',
    'src/components/Input/Input.js',
  ],
  output: {
    exports: 'named',
    dir: 'dist/',
    format: 'cjs',
    chunkFileNames: 'chunks/[name]-[hash].js',
  },
  plugins: [
    external(),
    babel({ exclude: 'node_modules/**', plugins: ['external-helpers'] }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
  ],
};
```

**index.js**

```
import Button from './components/Button/Button';
import Input from './components/Input/Input';

exports.Button = Button;
exports.Input = Input;
```

So this results in two files, `Button.js` and `Input.js` being built for each component which is great. But is it possible to bring in both components without the rest of the library in one `import` statement?

**Notes**

- The library currently uses Rollup but I don't think we *need* it if there's an easier solution.
- I feel like using the `experimentalCodeSplitting` feature isn't the ideal solution for this and I don't really like having the chunk files.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: You are not thinking about this the right way. You are making a *library*, not an application. Code splitting is the responsiblility of the *consuming* code, not you. If you want to provide a minified stripped down bundle of the whole lib as a convenience that's cool, but anything more fine-grained is on your users.

Comment: @JaredSmith Interesting. So my consuming applications would need to handle the code splitting. I'm just doing rough tests by using the VS Code extension ImportCost.  When you mention a 'stripped down bundle' what do you mean by that?

Comment: You provide a minified tree-shook bundled UMD with your entire library for ease of use for e.g. development/experimentation/CDN, but have the source be ES6 modules. Anybody who cares about payload size is already going to have a minification/bundling pipeline, and they all know how to work with those. They can just import the relevant source files and use their own tools on them. Everybody has their preferred build setup, let your users roll with it. Even if it's internal use only, build processes change. Don't needlessly couple them to your UI library.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks. This definitely makes sense. Though, how do libraries like React and Styled Components do it to where I can import in only one component and the Import Cost plugin shows the weight of just that component?

Comment: I don't understand the question (I don't use VSCode for one thing). If you're using native imports, then you'll only get what you import (and the transitive dependencies). React et. al. don't do anything special. Just look at the source code.

Comment: @Yuschick how did you proceed ? i am experiencing the same thing. except that, i would like my files to be compiled back to es5, since it is common to exclude node_modules from being transpiled and requiring from source wouldn't be enough.

Comment: Did you solve this? Trying to do same thin.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say leave optimisations of that kind to the host application. Make your package small, but not strange to use. If you are enabling static ES6 imports, they can be tree-shaken when the host bundles.

If you export it

```
export { default as Button } from './components/Button/Button'
export { default as Input } from './components/Input/Input'
```

and import like

```
import { Button } from 'my-library';
```

Users can shake the `Input` from your library when it bundles. But leave those choices to your users and their choice of bundler.

Now, you can use your `files` and `main` declaration in `package.json` to allow for multiple types of imports. If you set `main` to point to your `index.js`, but include folders in `files` where your components are exported (say, as default exports in index.js' of their own), they can be reached both ways.

Note that this is still totally redundant, and perhaps a bit unorthodox, and might cause your package to actually increase in size.